# Docker database does not create tables

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a database in a Docker container to work along another Docker container for a website I'm trying to update. 
I have a dump of the previous database so it must be used it in the new database.
I created the docker compose file as follow:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  my_db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: my_db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my
      MYSQL_USER: my
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: my
    volumes:
      - ./database/mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./database/my_dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/my_dump.sql
    ulimits:
      memlock: "1500000"
  my:
    build: ./web/
    container_name: my
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
      - "4430:443"
    depends_on:
      - my_db
```

Where `my_dump.sql` is the dump of the previous database, and `mysqldata` a directory inside the database folder.

Now, If I run `sudo docker-compose build | docker-compose up` and then: 
`docker exec -it my_db bash`
`~ mariadb -u my -p my`
`MariaDB [my]> show tables;`
The output is :
`Empty set (0.000 sec)`\

So, the database exist, had been created, but never filled with the information of the bump file.

I can't show the dump file here, but when I used it on my virtual machine it worked fine.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory you put your scripts in is called 'initdb.d' because it's only used to initialize a database when the container starts. If a database already exists, the scripts are not run.

If you delete the contents of `./database/mysqldata` and try again, the script will be run.

Comment: The folder was empty, but after `sudo docker rm -f -v my_db` it worked